# import CSV value "number" into mysql as a number

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i am trying to import a csv file into mysql.
I want numbers(302716684182 without any (')) in the csv to be added to mysql as numbers. But the only way i have been able to import the "numbers" is to a "varchar" column.
If i try to import and change to "int" for example it changes the number to 2147483647 if i leave the mysql col type as "varchar".

```
$sqlsetval .= $heading['table_header']." = '". (int)$num."',";
```

I can only assume if my original value is a number i dont need to convert it integer.But when i try without (int) and change the mysql col type to "int", the result is a completely different number.

So my question is:
If my value is a number in the csv how do i add it to mysql as a number and what column type should i be using in mysql?

I've always assumed 'int' was for numbers and 'varchar' was for strings? Or am i overthinking and it doest matter that it brings a number in as a string?

Comment: no its not a negative number, its an id number not enclosed in any characters

Comment: Google that number 2147483647 and you will find your solution; it has been asked already.

Comment: e.g. item_id = 302716684182 instead of item_id = "302716684182"

Comment: Steve, my answer fixes your issue. Don't use int, use bigint.

Comment: ah so thats the max integer value as Mark Overton says

Comment: Sorry your all too quick on here LOL thanks mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the data type 'bigint' with a value of '20'.

The range of an int data type is -2,147,483,648 **to** 2,147,483,647.

The range of a bigint data type is -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 **to** 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Highlighted the word 'to' so you can see it is two different numbers.